# Best way to encrypt the system drive on Windows

Tags: windows-10, bitlocker, disk-encryption, veracrypt

I am looking for the best way to encrypt the system disk on a Windows 10 Professional PC.

I think that the best should mean something like FileVault on Mac OS X, because the system disk is well encrypted and you don't need to enter the key password when you boot the system.

I searched some info about BitLocker on Windows, with and without the TPM module (https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/6229/how-to-use-bitlocker-on-drives-without-tpm/), but if you don't have the TPM module you will need and external USB drive to save the key on.

I also read some info about VeraCrypt (https://www.veracrypt.fr/en/Downloads.html), and it works the same way (you will need an external USB drive).

Isn't really any other way to encrypt the system drive without having the TPM module or an external USB drive mounted on the device?

Answer (score 1):

> I think that the best should mean something like FileVault on Mac OS
> X, because the system disk is well encrypted and you don't need to
> enter the key password when you boot the system.

BitLocker is the Windows equivalent of FileVault.

> I also read some info about VeraCrypt
> (https://www.veracrypt.fr/en/Downloads.html), and it works the same
> way (you will need an external USB drive).

VeraCrypt supports FDE of the system disk, in other words, you can encrypt the disk Windows is installed on.

> Isn't really any other way to encrypt the system drive without having
> the TPM module or an external USB drive mounted on the device?
>
> I searched some info about BitLocker on Windows, with and without the TPM module (https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/6229/how-to-use-bitlocker-on-drives-without-tpm/), but if you don't have the TPM module you will need and external USB drive to save the key on.

Backing up your recovery key is an optional step, BitLocker, can be used on a system without a TPM.  So, unfortunately, it seems you have eliminated the only two methods, to accomplish Full Disk Encryption with Windows (BitLocker and VeraCrypt/TrueCrypt).